# ImageView not filling screen

Tags: android

I want my green picture file to fill my android application's screen, but it does not fill the screen no matter what I try and I don't know why. I tried applying the fitXY attribute, I tried setting the width and height of the imageview in java to values larger than the screen width/height and it still doesn't fill the screen. It appears to be stuck at some fixed dimension. The preview image in the xml perspective shows me this https://i.stack.imgur.com/CycPQ.jpg and the actual outcome is this https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmMBI.jpg

I do not know what to try anymore. Can someone please recommend something? I have included the xml code below.

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Capture"
    android:id="@+id/capture"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgClose"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
    android:padding="20dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/redReference"
    android:src="@drawable/red"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/blueReference"
    android:src="@drawable/blue"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/green"
    android:src="@drawable/green"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: set the height and width to match_parent, you have it as wrap_content currently for the green ImageView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is not clear from this code what exactly is wrong, here are some things to check:

- `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` should have the value `match_parent`.
- Make sure that the size of the parent of the FrameLayout matches the size of the screen.

**EDIT:** This worked for me (I have removed some colours):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/capture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:text="Capture" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgClose"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
    android:padding="20dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/redReference"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/green" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**EDIT 2:** if you want to display just a colour you don't need to put an image there. Just use the colour code. This way you can also remove the scaleType line.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem for me. I figured there should be a way to set the screen to a color code, but I would need it to overlap the camera preview of my app and was unsure how to do that so I just decided to use an image.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked! Using a colour may also slightly improve the performance of the app. FYI, a good idea would be to add colour codes in `res/values/colors.xml`. A nice list of material design colours can be found here: https://gist.github.com/kalehv/bae765c756e94455ed88

You can call them by `android:src="@color/colorName"` in an ImageView.

Comment: Oh I didn't know I could do that. Thanks, I'll try it out right now.

Comment: Update: Got it working with the color code way and it looks great. I really appreciate you telling me that.

Comment: Great! Depending on your scenario, you might also want to give a background colour to the FrameLayout instead of putting a full screen image. To do so, just remove the background image and add this to the first FrameLayout: `android:background="@color/someColour"`.